# long format parent child dataframe to wide format with full hierarchy

Tags: python, r, dataframe, reshape

I have following long-format dataframe with two columns containing a nested parent-child hierarchy:

```
parent,child,child_level
d     ,sf   ,x
d     ,st   ,x
d     ,s0   ,x
sf    ,gr4  ,l
sf    ,gr3  ,l
st    ,grd  ,l
st    ,gr9  ,l
s0    ,n7   ,l
s0    ,b12  ,l
grd   ,nyvc ,b
gr3   ,trub2,b
b12   ,ngb2 ,b
b12   ,ggb8 ,b
nyvc  ,xtr2d,i
trub2 ,xtuD ,i
gr4   ,stab3,i
gr9   ,ubc8 ,i
n7    ,ubc2 ,i
ggb8  ,drik2,i
```

My goal is to un-nest the parent and child columns to wide format. The column names should correspond to the respective level in the child_level column:

```
 ,x ,l  ,b    ,i
d,sf,gr4,NA   ,stab3
d,sf,gr3,trub2,xtuD
d,st,grd,nyvc ,xtr2d
d,st,gr9,NA   ,ubc8
d,s0,n7 ,NA   ,ubc2
d,s0,b12,ngb2 ,NA
d,s0,b12,ggb8 ,drik2
```

There is no additional information denoting order or level rank, which is only emergent from the child and parent columns. Also, not all rows of the output table will contain all hierarchy levels - these should be filled with NA.

**EDIT1 (for clarification):** An R or Python solution would work, so I am presenting a generic input table (to be read e.g. as csv). Also, the table below is hand-crafted - I don't actually know how to get there programmatically.

**EDIT2:** The rows are not ordered, i.e. child level can be in any order, so it would have to be some recursive approach.

Comment: I don't understand how you actually get from the input table to the output? What is the 'root' column? Could you actually post a complete input data set and what output you expect?

Comment: the "root" column is just the lowest possible level. the output I would like to have is the table below. the complete dataset is very long, and not ordered, so it's not useful in describing the data structure

Comment: Again, this does not really explain how to identify the  'lowest possible level'. In your example the column 'root' seems to be populated by a single value from the 'parent' column--the rest of which are dropped? There is not a need to post the full data, but show a shorter yet complete data input and the desired output. In addition, please use dput() so the data can be easily pasted into a script--rather than everybody having to copy the data, paste it into a spread sheet, save it as a data file, and then import it into a script.

Comment: I thought that's what I did? the top table IS a shorter version of the original data, and the bottom table IS the desired output. also, this is not an R-specific question - python is also fine, so I felt a dput-structure would constrain people.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer**

I now have an approach which works as long as you know the order of descendance, that is, the order in which we need to sort the `child_level` vector. If you don't know that, we should be able to calculate the order, but for now I assume it is known.

The approach is based on:

1. first calculating the `parent_level` as well
2. nest the the data frame by both `parent_level` and  `child_level`
3. a custom function that can be used with `purrr::accumulate2` or `purrr::reduce2` that joins all data.frames in a row using a `left_join` and in case an existing column is joined again, the respective columns are merged into one

Before applying this custom `join_merge` function:

4. the nested data.frames need to be sorted in order of descendance (`child_level`)
5. the column names `parent` and `child` are replaced with the values of `parent_level` and `child_level`
6. finally `parent_level` and `child_level` are combined into a vector called `arg_ls` which is passed as `.y` argument to `accumulate2` (or alternatively `reduce2`)

I hope this works on your real data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tribble(
  ~ parent, ~child, ~child_level,
  "d"     ,"sf"   ,"x",
  "d"     ,"st"   ,"x",
  "d"     ,"s0"   ,"x",
  "sf"    ,"gr4"  ,"l",
  "sf"    ,"gr3"  ,"l",
  "st"    ,"grd"  ,"l",
  "st"    ,"gr9"  ,"l",
  "s0"    ,"n7"   ,"l",
  "s0"    ,"b12"  ,"l",
  "grd"   ,"nyvc" ,"b",
  "gr3"   ,"trub2","b",
  "b12"   ,"ngb2" ,"b",
  "b12"   ,"ggb8" ,"b",
  "nyvc"  ,"xtr2d","i",
  "trub2" ,"xtuD" ,"i",
  "gr4"   ,"stab3","i",
  "gr9"   ,"ubc8" ,"i",
  "n7"    ,"ubc2" ,"i",
  "ggb8"  ,"drik2","i"
)
# in a first step we calculate the `parent_level`
dat <- dat %>% 
  left_join(., select(., -parent), by = c("parent" = "child")) %>% 
  rename("child_level" = "child_level.x",
         "parent_level" = "child_level.y") %>% 
  mutate(parent_level = replace_na(parent_level, "o"))

# we need this function to work with accumulate2 or reduce2
join_merge <- function(df1, df2, .rename) {
  res <- left_join(df1, df2, by = .rename[1]) 

  # in case an existing column is joined again, we need to merge it together
  if(length(colnames(select(res, starts_with(all_of(.rename[2]))))) > 1) {
    res <- mutate(res, across(matches(paste0(.rename[2], ".x")), 
                              ~ if_else(is.na(.x), eval(sym(paste0(.rename[2], ".y"))), .x))) %>% 
      select(-all_of(paste0(.rename[2], ".y"))) %>% 
      rename(!! .rename[2] := paste0(.rename[2], ".x"))
  }
  res
}


# accumulate is used to show how the final result is buildt
dat %>% 
  nest_by(child_level, parent_level) %>% 
  arrange(child_level == "i", desc(child_level)) %>% 
  mutate(arg_ls = list(c(parent_level, child_level))) %>% 
  mutate(data = list(rename_with(data,
                                 ~ paste0(child_level),
                                 "child") %>%
           rename_with(~ paste0(parent_level),
                       "parent"))) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(dat_acc = accumulate2(data,
                              arg_ls[-1],
                              join_merge)) %>% 
  pull(dat_acc)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   o     x    
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 d     sf   
#> 2 d     st   
#> 3 d     s0   
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   o     x     l    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 d     sf    gr4  
#> 2 d     sf    gr3  
#> 3 d     st    grd  
#> 4 d     st    gr9  
#> 5 d     s0    n7   
#> 6 d     s0    b12  
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#>   o     x     l     b    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 d     sf    gr4   <NA> 
#> 2 d     sf    gr3   trub2
#> 3 d     st    grd   nyvc 
#> 4 d     st    gr9   <NA> 
#> 5 d     s0    n7    <NA> 
#> 6 d     s0    b12   ngb2 
#> 7 d     s0    b12   ggb8 
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>   o     x     l     b     i    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 d     sf    gr4   <NA>  <NA> 
#> 2 d     sf    gr3   trub2 xtuD 
#> 3 d     st    grd   nyvc  xtr2d
#> 4 d     st    gr9   <NA>  <NA> 
#> 5 d     s0    n7    <NA>  <NA> 
#> 6 d     s0    b12   ngb2  <NA> 
#> 7 d     s0    b12   ggb8  drik2
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>   o     x     l     b     i    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 d     sf    gr4   <NA>  stab3
#> 2 d     sf    gr3   trub2 xtuD 
#> 3 d     st    grd   nyvc  xtr2d
#> 4 d     st    gr9   <NA>  ubc8 
#> 5 d     s0    n7    <NA>  ubc2 
#> 6 d     s0    b12   ngb2  <NA> 
#> 7 d     s0    b12   ggb8  drik2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: nice! however, on the real data I am getting an error: 
"Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `data`.
x Names must be unique.
x These names are duplicated:"

I think it may be because I sometimes have children that have their parents within the same child level, which really shouldn't be. I need to figure out what's going on there first

Answer (score 0):

Without further information here is how I would generally approach the problem. I'm showing a `tidyverse` solution, but surely this can be done in base R as well.

```
data <- structure(list(child = structure(c(10L, 11L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 8L, 13L, 7L, 3L, 16L, 17L, 12L, 15L, 14L, 2L), .Label = c("b12", 
"drik2", "ggb8", "gr4", "grd", "n7", "ngb2", "nyvc", "s0", "sf", 
"st", "stab3", "trub2", "ubc2", "ubc8", "xtr2d", "xtuD"), class = "factor"), 
    parent = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 
    7L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 13L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 3L), .Label = c("b12", 
    "d", "ggb8", "gr3", "gr4", "gr9", "grd", "n7", "nyvc", "s0", 
    "sf", "st", "trub2"), class = "factor"), child_level = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("b", "i", "t", "x"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))

library(tidyverse)

pivot <- data %>% mutate(unique = rownames(data)) %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = unique, names_from = child_level, values_from = child) %>% select(!unique)
```

The input looks like this:

```
# > data
#    child parent child_level
# 1     sf      d           x
# 2     st      d           x
# 3     s0      d           x
# 4    gr4     sf           t
# 5    grd     sf           t
# 6    grd     st           t
# 7     n7     s0           t
# 8    b12     s0           t
# 9   nyvc    grd           b
# 10 trub2    gr3           b
# 11  ngb2    b12           b
# 12  ggb8    b12           b
# 13 xtr2d   nyvc           i
# 14  xtuD  trub2           i
# 15 stab3    gr4           i
# 16  ubc8    gr9           i
# 17  ubc2     n7           i
# 18 drik2   ggb8           i
```

And it'll output this:

```
# > pivot
# # A tibble: 18 x 4
#    x     t     b     i    
#    <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>
#  1 sf    NA    NA    NA   
#  2 st    NA    NA    NA   
#  3 s0    NA    NA    NA   
#  4 NA    gr4   NA    NA   
#  5 NA    grd   NA    NA   
#  6 NA    grd   NA    NA   
#  7 NA    n7    NA    NA   
#  8 NA    b12   NA    NA   
#  9 NA    NA    nyvc  NA   
# 10 NA    NA    trub2 NA   
# 11 NA    NA    ngb2  NA   
# 12 NA    NA    ggb8  NA   
# 13 NA    NA    NA    xtr2d
# 14 NA    NA    NA    xtuD 
# 15 NA    NA    NA    stab3
# 16 NA    NA    NA    ubc8 
# 17 NA    NA    NA    ubc2 
# 18 NA    NA    NA    drik2
```

Comment: this is not what I need - the hierarchies between child and parent are lost